# Account checkout-fields not working in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am designing my selected fields in woocommerce checkout-form although some work fine but the fields associated with account are not working properly. 
I took help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581310/wordpress-woocommerce-show-and-modify-account-fields-on-checkout-page) answer but still account fields didn't load properly.
[image]

I am using this code for generating these fields in form-billing.php

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'account_username', $checkout->checkout_fields['account']['account_username'],
          $checkout->get_value( 'account_username') );

woocommerce_form_field( 'account_password', $checkout->checkout_fields['account']['account_password'],
          $checkout->get_value( 'account_password') );

woocommerce_form_field( 'account_password-2', $checkout->checkout_fields['account']['account_password-2'], $checkout->get_value( 'account_password-2') );
```

any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer of my problem , I add filters custom_override in my themes function.php and make 3 fields of my need which is username , password and password-2 and simple call it in my form-billing.php

Add this code to my **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['account']['account_username'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Username', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('username', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );

     $fields['account']['account_password'] = array(
       'type' => 'password',
       'required'  => true,
        'label' => __('Account password', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => _x('Password', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'class' => array('form-row-wide')
     );

     $fields['account']['account_password-2'] = array(
       'type' => 'password',
       'required'  => true,
        'label' => __('Confirm your password', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => _x('Re-password', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'class' => array('form-row-wide')

     );



     return $fields;
}
```

and then called my fields in my **form-billing.php**

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'account_username', $checkout->checkout_fields['account']['account_username'],
                  $checkout->get_value( 'account_username') );

woocommerce_form_field( 'account_password', $checkout->checkout_fields['account']['account_password'], $checkout->get_value( 'account_password') );

woocommerce_form_field( 'account_password-2', $checkout->checkout_fields['account']['account_password-2'], $checkout->get_value( 'account_password-2') );
```

Note: I override these line on this loop in form-billing.php

```
<?php foreach ( $checkout->checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field ) : ?>

    <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) ); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It solved my issue , May be it is of some help to you :)